# django-keyboard-shorcuts throwing exception

Tags: python, django

I am using django web framework for my website. I want to use keyboard shortcut in website,so I followed the details given in internet,installed `django-keyboard-shorcuts` packages,added following code in settings.py:

```
   HOTKEYS = [

        {'keys': 'alt+m',
        'link': '/data/',
        },
           ]
```

Still it's not working,throwing error.can anyone help me on this?

Comment: what package you installed? give error stack trace.

Comment: Installed django-keyboard-shortcuts 0.0.7 package.

Comment: edit your question and give stack trace of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include following code in every html pages:

```
 {% load hotkeys %}
  <html>
  <head>
  {% setup_hotkeys %}
```

This will load the hotkeys and enable the keyboard shortcut keys.